# Solved: Problems defining large custom messages

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, add-message-files

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

I have a problem with a ROS_Node and large custom Messages. My Node shloud be capable of Publishing two ROS_Messages. These two custom Messages consist of several other custom messages to generate a deeper structur.

Example:

```
add_message_files(
   FILES
   A.msg
   B.msg
   C.msg
   D.msg
   ....
   MasterA.msg
   MasterB.msg
 )
```

The message Master.msg is dependend to A,B,C,D..... and the MasterB consits of three floats and D.
When I build the project no error is shown.
When trying to acces the Message MasterA works fine but MasterB does not show me the property of D.

Is there like a maximum number of Messages, or what could be the reason? Since Message MasterA builds fine, I think I've done everything right concerning message generation and so on..

Sorry for the bad explanation, but i don't know how to describe the problem any better.

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316065/solved:-problems-defining-large-custom-messages/) by [MarcelKr](https://answers.ros.org/users/40095/marcelkr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-02-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-02-19**:
Can you show us the message definition of MasterB. Also what exactly do you mean by

> MasterB does not show me the property of D

Can you access each of its members apart from the instance of D?

**Comment by [MarcelKr](https://answers.ros.org/users/40095/marcelkr/) on 2019-02-20**:
"Can you access each of its members apart from the instance of D?"

Yes, that was exactly my problem. The reason seemed to be, that i added D to the message definition after I builded the project for the first time.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-20**:
@MarcelKr: please post your last edit as an answer and accept your own answer.

That way it's much clearer that you've resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Edit: Managed to solve the problem!**

The problem was, that I edited the message after I defined it. I don't know why but CMAKE seems to stick on the original definition, even after deleting the msg.h-files. After deleting the whole project and rebuilding it, everything works fine.

---

Originally posted by [MarcelKr](https://answers.ros.org/users/40095/marcelkr/) with karma: 16 on 2019-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0